# Angular 10 to 12 update causing error Uncaught RangeError: Wrong length

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I have just upgraded my Angular application from version 10 to version 12 and when I run 'ng serve' there are no build errors, but then in the console it gives me the error "Uncaught RangeError: Wrong length!" from _typed-buffer.js:157. In the stack trace there is app-routing.module.ts:104 and auth-guard.service.ts:12 towards the bottom. I am not sure how to get past this error. None of the application loads because of this. On auth-guard.service.ts line 12 there is

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private location: Location) {}
```

I have tried updating to latest node and npm versions 14.17.0 and 7.13.0. I have tried ng update and updating all my packages. Just can't seem to get past this error. There is not much when I search google about this error and Angular 12. Has anybody had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, there are some changes migrating from angular 10 to angular 12 that have to do with router and you maybe have to solve manualy

> If you use the router, the default value of relativeLinkResolution has
> changed from legacy to corrected. If your application previously used
> the default by not specifying a value in the ExtraOptions and uses
> relative links when navigating from children of empty path routes, you
> will need to update your RouterModule's configuration to specifically
> specify legacy for [relativeLinkResolution](https://v11.angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#relativeLinkResolution). See the documentation for
> more details.

And

> routerLinkActiveOptions property of RouterLinkActive now has a more
> specific type. You may need to update code accessing this property to
> align with the changes.

And

> In the Angular Router, the options deprecated in v4 for
> initialNavigation have been removed. If you previously used enabled or
> true, now choose enabledNonBlocking or enabledBlocking.

And

> If you previously used false or legacy_disabled, now use disabled. In
> the Angular Router's routerLink, preserveQueryParams has been removed,
> use queryParamsHandling="preserve" instead.

And

> If you were accessing the routerLink values of queryParams, fragment
> or queryParamsHandling you might need to relax the typing to also
> accept undefined and null

More possible things to explore [here](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=10.0-12.0)

Comment: I have gone through the whole conversion guide from 10 to 12, but none of those suggestions fixed that error. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled npm packages multiple times and it will only work with npm install --legacy-peer-deps. Still can't get past the error.

Comment: Please post the code for `routing.module.ts:104 and auth-guard.service.ts:12`